# What is the performance difference when using 100+ routes in one firebase cloud function, and spliting routes to multiple cloud functions?

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions

i am using firebase cloud functions for my current project (learning management system using reactjs,nodejs and firebase).i have over 100 routes in single function called api. so i would like to know what is the performance difference if i split these routes into multiple functions.

sample code

```
app.get("/getReviews", (req, res) => {
  let queryString = req.query.id || "";
  console.log(req.query.id);
  admin
    .firestore()
    .collection("users")
    .doc(queryString)
    .collection("reviews")
    .get()
    .then((data) => {
      let reviews = [];
      data.forEach((doc) => {
        reviews.push(doc.data());
      });
      console.log(reviews);
      return res.status(200).json(reviews);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
      return res.status(500).json({ error: err });
    });
});

exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Comment: I suggest benchmarking it yourself.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks for your reply :)

Comment: @DougStevenson I am actually interested in this questions. I am writing an API at the moment and looking to deploy it to cloud function. And as I don't have it ready, I cannot benchmark it myself. My concern is not the performance but the cost. In my understanding, splitting a single express app into separate endpoint allows the endpoint to load only dependencies it needs, which may have a significant effect on cold start time. While an improvement from 200ms to 100ms response time is not noticeable performance wise, it may cut the cost by half. Any comments or data to share?